# PayPal Express on mobile - no notes to seller/merchant

Tags: paypal

I have a website where I am using Cart66 that sends orders to PayPal Express.

Assuming the customer does not have nor wish to create a PayPal account:

When going through desktop - the customer gets a chance to add notes to merchant/seller. However, when using mobile, there is no such field.

Cart66 support says it is a PayPal issue... But I have been over all setings I can find... But maybe i am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like in-context does not support it yet

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/popup/
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/integration/

(That said, inspecting the Cart66 - they are not calling the new "In-Context" URL that is specified in requirements, but I still that it the reason)